# How to upload big data from two microservices at once?

Tags: rest, architecture, microservices

How to upload big data from two microservices at once?

I have microservice A and B.

Service A unloads an archive containing large data (1..2 GB) upon HTTP request. Part of this data is stored in the database of service A, and part of the data is stored in the database of service B.

What is the best way to organize the logic of this unloading?

1. Use only REST. Service A requests data from service B via HTTP. Service B sends data via HTTP. Service A generates an archive and sends it at the request of the client.

[image]

2. Use docker volume. Service A creates a directory in the shared docker volume. Service A requests data from service B. Service B places its upload file on the shared volume. Service A places its part in the volume directory, archives everything and sends the archive to the client.

[image]

3. Something else.

Comment: _"What is the best way to organize the logic of this unloading?"_ - can you please define criteria for "best"? Storage effective? Performance/speed effective?

Comment: I am waiting for a response that will evaluate my variant according to the criteria you provided. I also expect alternatives and their subjective analysis.